# Getting information from a shared object on the adobe media server

Tags: adobe, flash-builder, rtmp, shared-objects, flash-media-server

I am currently stuck and cant find any answers anywhere!! So any help at all would be great!
Currently Im trying to create a sharedObject on a client and send a string from the client containing information based on phone hardware(e.g. accelerometer and geolocation) to ams. From here I want to be able to access information from the sharedObject on the server in the main.asc to use elsewhere!
This is where the problem is occurring I cant access the shared object sent by the client. I sent my shared object like this:

```
 //It's a best practice to always check for a successful NetConnection
                protected function onNetStatus(event:NetStatusEvent):void
                {
                    switch(event.info.code)//Check for a successful NetConnection
                    {
                        case "NetConnection.Connect.Success"://If the netConnection is a success#
                            so = SharedObject.getRemote("Data", nc.uri, false);//
                            so.connect(nc);//connect the sharedObject to the srever
                            so.addEventListener(SyncEvent.SYNC, syncHandler);//The sync listener
                            publishCamera(); //Publish the video
                        case "NetStream.Publish.Start"://If the netStream is a success
                            //etc
                    }
                }   



//It's a best practice to always check for a successful NetConnection
            protected function syncHandler(event:SyncEvent):void
            {
                so.setProperty("username", nameForData);
                so.setProperty("age", 21);
                so.setProperty("nationality", "irish");
                trace("Local"+so.data.username);
```

Im just not sure how to access so from server side!! I know this works as I have tested it but if there are better ways to implement it I would be glad to get advice!Below is proof that it is hitting the server
[image: ams admin console not working]

**Update**
Still stuck so I am adding a bounty and updating where I am and how I have progressed!
I have the information hitting the server(sometimes its not constant I dont know why)
Example is sometimes I get this in the admin console most times i have no information in the properties tab
[image: ams admin console]
What I am trying to do is to get the file to save every time I flush() the shared object so  I can use it elsewhere

My server code is straight from the adobe api this is how it looks in the main asc:

in my onAppStart() I added these lines at the end:

```
application.allowDebug = true;
application.clearOnAppStop = false;
var Shared = SharedObject.get("Data", true);
trace("Name: "+Shared.name);
trace("Username: "+Shared.getProperty("username"));
```

in my onAppStop() I added these lines at the end:

```
var Shared = SharedObject.get("Data", true);
Shared.clear();
```

Comment: have you tried writing it to a json file?

Answer (score 0):

The serverside code for shared objects is (almost) the same as the client side.

So using `so.getProperty(propertyName)` should do the job.

If not check the [server side shared object reference](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flashmediaserver/ssaslr/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d11a11afc95e-7e63SSASLR.html#WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d11a11afc95e-7f5aSSASLR) from adobe. Maybe that helps.

Hope i didn't missunderstand your question.